# PHP project referring to Java class file

Tags: java, php, class, applet

I have a java class file in a folder in php project and it is an applet that will be used by the PHP/JS file I have in this project. When trying to view contents of class file I receive this:

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The class file is not on the classpath

I wanted to include() this class file within my php file and find that server tells me "No such file or directory", so I figure it has to do with this CoreException.

Now is fun part. I can save class file from www.something.com/fold1/fold2/class_file.class but not from www.something.com/fold2/class_file.class. Reason for this is that the server will ignore fold1 but in my project the directory structure is like the first url with fold1 included. I need the second url to work though.

I think this is really two questions but hopefully its really one problem. Thanks for helping

Comment: I think i might need to use codebase in my applet tag in html. will see

Comment: yes! that was the problem. so simple too

Comment: You don't have to include it in php. The browser has to request it as it does with images.